# Visualize Random Forest and VSURF

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to visually sanity check a random forest/vsurf object I've created.  Is there a way to do that in R?

I saw this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree, but after trying the answers I end with this error:

```
Error in getTree(rf.model, 1, labelVar = TRUE) : 
  No forest component in rf.model
```

Reproducible Example with code from the stack.exchange answer above:

```
#**************************
#return the rules of a tree
#**************************
getConds<-function(tree){
  #store all conditions into a list
  conds<-list()
  #start by the terminal nodes and find previous conditions
  id.leafs<-which(tree$status==-1)
  j<-0
  for(i in id.leafs){
    j<-j+1
    prevConds<-prevCond(tree,i)
    conds[[j]]<-prevConds$cond
    while(prevConds$id>1){
      prevConds<-prevCond(tree,prevConds$id)
      conds[[j]]<-paste(conds[[j]]," & ",prevConds$cond)
      if(prevConds$id==1){
        conds[[j]]<-paste(conds[[j]]," => ",tree$prediction[i])
        break()
      }
    }

  }

  return(conds)
}

#**************************
#find the previous conditions in the tree
#**************************
prevCond<-function(tree,i){
  if(i %in% tree$right_daughter){
    id<-which(tree$right_daughter==i)
    cond<-paste(tree$split_var[id],">",tree$split_point[id])
  }
  if(i %in% tree$left_daughter){
    id<-which(tree$left_daughter==i)
    cond<-paste(tree$split_var[id],"<",tree$split_point[id])
  }

  return(list(cond=cond,id=id))
}

#remove spaces in a word
collapse<-function(x){
  x<-sub(" ","_",x)

  return(x)
}


data(iris)
require(randomForest)
mod.rf <- VSURF(Species ~ ., data=iris,
                ntree = 1000, parallel =  TRUE, keep.forest = TRUE)
tree<-getTree(mod.rf, k=1, labelVar=TRUE)
#rename the name of the column
colnames(tree)<-sapply(colnames(tree),collapse)
rules<-getConds(tree)
print(rules)
```